# How to pass a data to child component only once during mounting component in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I would like to pass data to child component but do not want to bind it when the data changes in the parent

```
<parent :val="myval">
     <child :initialval="val"></child>
</parent>
```

This code binds my initial value to `myval`, I just want it to be passed first time and do not want `initialval` to be reactive to changes of my val.

Can I do it without setting a local variable in  `mounted()` function of `child` component?

Answer (score 3):

You want to initialize the component's data from a prop:

```
<parent :val="myval">
     <child :initialval="val"></child>
</parent>
```

and in the child:

```
data() {
    return {
        value: initialval
    };
}
```

then use the component's data item (`value` in my example here) instead of the prop for whatever you're doing in the component.

Comment: Okie, is it same as setting value in mounted vs setting in data function. Is there an order in which these are called?

Comment: @Masade There is an order for the lifecycle. It begins with 'beforeCreate', then 'created', then 'beforeMount'. You can see the full documentation here: 

https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram

Comment: I would only put things in lifecycle hooks that didn't have a natural place in the ordinary declaration of the component. In this case, you're just defining data, which goes in the `data` function. The `mounted` function is typically for things that need to work with `vm.$el`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the v-once attribute

```
<child :initialval="val" v-once></child>
```

Comment: but that would make my child component render only once right?